# How to async way call 10 functions and collect all results and know when all are finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deferred

I am using deferred module for Node.js and I have created deferred functions which fetch data from distant server. I need to fetch 10 files from different distant server, how to do this with promise to know when all are finished and fetch all then results in array ?
At the moment I have closure and I am fetching next file only when I have done with previous but it is sync and slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://npmjs.org/package/deferred) of what I assume is the module you're using, you can do this:

```
deferred(delayedAdd(2, 3), delayedAdd(3, 5), delayedAdd(1, 7))(function (result) {`
    console.log(result); // [5, 8, 8]`
});
```

E.g.:

```
deferred(promise1, promise2, promise3)(function (result) {
    // `result` is an array of the results
});
```

On the link above, search for "Grouping Promises" (although it doesn't have much more than the above).

If you have an array of promises, you can use [`Function#apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3) to do the above:

```
deferred.apply(undefined, theArray)(function (result) {
    // `result` is an array of the results
});
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have idea how to deal with array of promises when number is not known

Comment: @PaolaJ.: Sure: `deferred.apply(undefined, theArray)(function(result) { ... });` More: [`Function#apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3). At one point I was going to edit that in, clearly I should have. :-) *Edit:* And now I have.