# How to know when multiple async functions are finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

How to solve this async problem ? (using node.js)

A promise is iterating through a list, and multiple async functions are called with each iteration. How do I know when all async functions are finished, so that I can resolve the promise ?

All I found yet is to use a `setTimeout()` which isn't efficient at all.

Here is a simplified sample of my code :

```
function myFunction(parameter){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var resultToReturn = []
        _.each(list, function(el){
            doSomethingAsync(el, function(result){
                resultToReturn.push(result)
            });
            doSomethingElseAsync(el, function(result){
                resultToReturn.push(result)
            });
        });
        // How to call this ⬋ only when all async functions are finished ?
        resolve(resultToReturn)
    });
}

myFunction(IAmAParameter).then(function(resultFromPromise){
    console.log(resultFromPromise);
});
```

I know this kind of question was already asked many times, but answers were too specific and not relevant in this case.

Ex. :

- [How to async way call 10 functions and collect all results and know when all are finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392901/how-to-async-way-call-10-functions-and-collect-all-results-and-know-when-all-are)
- [How to know when a collection of getJSON() requests are finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509586/how-to-know-when-all-of-theses-requests-are-finished)

Comment: With promises you can use `Promise.all(promises).then(doSomething)`

Comment: There is a `.catch` with `Promise.all()`, and it can be a gotcha...

Comment: @dandavis: You mean you'd prefer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31424561/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi: perhaps something like that if needed, just raising awareness...

Comment: I think you need a combination of `Promise.map` and  `Promise.all`
    function myFunction(parameter){
         return Promise.map(list, function(el) {
              return Promise.all([
                  doSomethingAsync(el, function(result){
                    return result;
                  }),
                  doSomethingElseAsync(el, function(result){
                    return result;
                  })
              ])
         })
    }

You will also need to use `bluebird` for the `Promise.map`

Comment: Using multiple `Promise.all` solved my issue. Thanks !